# How Can I find the median of the first values of each list in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
values = [(u'[23,4,77,890,455]',10),(u'[11,2,50,1,11]',20),(u'[10,5,1,22,04]',30)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['list','A'])
df.show()

+-----------------+---+
|           list_1|  A|
+-----------------+---+
|[23,4,77,890,455]| 10|
|   [11,2,50,1,11]| 20|
|   [10,5,1,22,04]| 30|
+-----------------+---+
```

I want to convert the above spark dataframe into a frame such that first element in each list of column "list_1" should be in one column i.e 23,11,10 in first column 4,2,5 in second column etc.I tried

```
df.select([df.list_1[i] for i in range(5)])
```

But as I have around 4000 values in each list, the above seems to be time consuming.**The end goal is to find the median of each column in resulting dataframe.**

I use pyspark.

Comment: Do they always have same length, and never a empty list?

Comment: yes same length in all rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at `posexplode`. 
I used your small example and transformed the dataframe into another dataframe with the 5 columns and the respective values from the array in each line.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([([23,4,77,890,455],10),([11,2,50,1,11],20),\
([10,5,1,22,04],30)], ["list1","A"])
df1.select(posexplode("list1"),"list1","A")\ #explodes the array and creates multiple rows for each element with the position in the columns "col" and "pos"
.groupBy("list1","A").pivot("pos")\          #group by your initial values and take the "pos" column as pivot to create 1 new column per element here
.agg(max("col")).show(truncate=False)        #collect the values
```

Output:

```python
+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|list1                |A  |0  |1  |2  |3  |4  |
+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|[10, 5, 1, 22, 4]    |30 |10 |5  |1  |22 |4  |
|[11, 2, 50, 1, 11]   |20 |11 |2  |50 |1  |11 |
|[23, 4, 77, 890, 455]|10 |23 |4  |77 |890|455|
+---------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Of course afterwards you can continue to compute the mean or whatever you want for the individual array values.

In case that your list1 column contains strings and not the direct array you need to extract the array first. You could do this with `regexp_extract` and `split`. It also works for float values in the string.

```python
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(u'[23.1,4,77,890,455]',10),(u'[11,2,50,1.1,11]',20),(u'[10,5,1,22,04.1]',30)], ["list1","A"])
df1 = df1.withColumn("list2",split(regexp_extract("list1","(([\d\.]+,)+[\d\.]+)",1),","))
df1.select(posexplode("list2"),"list1","A").groupBy("list1","A").pivot("pos").agg(max("col")).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi gaw, what if the 'A' was not there!?

Comment: ?Chris. If you only have the `list1` column in your initial dataframe, you can leave out the `A` column in the query: `.select(posexplode("list1"),"list1",).groupBy("list1").pivot("pos").agg(max("col")).show()`

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o287.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'posexplode(`list1`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not bigint;;
'Project [posexplode(list1#477L) AS List(), list1#477L]
+- LogicalRDD [list1#477L, _2#478L, _3#479L, _4#480L, _5#481L], false

Comment: Be aware that `posexplode()` requires the column name of the array from your original dataframe as string, so you should have `posexplode("list1")`

Comment: Yes its a string, gaw! But still the error pops up. But the values inside the list is float. Thats is the list_1 contains array<"float">

Comment: Then your example is misleading. Does the column list_1 contains a string or an array? if its an array it should work but your example shows a string. Can you verify the input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189072/discussion-between-gaw-and-ram-shanker-g).

Comment: Only for the sake of making an example i made it like that, my input is array<float>

Comment: Worked Like a charm! Thakuu gaw! It was minor carelessness from my part!! :)